# Fetch user info to sharedpreferences on Login Android

Tags: php, android, mysql, json, sharedpreferences

I've created an login activity on android, for that you need email address and password.

It working but since I'm new on android, I don't know how to fetch the rest of user information and save it in the sharedpreferences.

Please help me

login.php

```
<?php

//load and connect to MySQL database stuff
require("config.inc.php");

if (!empty($_POST)) {
    //gets user's info based of a username.
    $query = " 
            SELECT 
                user_id, 
                user_name,
                user_email,
                user_password,
                user_salt,              
                user_mobile,
                user_country
            FROM users 
            WHERE 
                user_email = :email 
        ";

    $query_params = array(
        ':email' => $_POST['user_email']
    );

    try {
        $stmt   = $db->prepare($query);
        $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);
    }
    catch (PDOException $ex) {
        // For testing, you could use a die and message. 
        //die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage());

        //or just use this use this one to product JSON data:
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Database Error 1. Please Try Again!";
        die(json_encode($response));

    }

    //This will be the variable to determine whether or not the user's information is correct.
    //we initialize it as false.
    $validated_info = false;

    //fetching all the rows from the query
    $row = $stmt->fetch();
    if ($row) {
        //if we encrypted the password, we would unencrypt it here, but in our case we just
        //compare the two passwords
        $check_password = hash('sha256', $_POST['user_password'] . $row['user_salt']);
        for($round = 0; $round < 65536; $round++) 
        {
            $check_password = hash('sha256', $check_password . $row['user_salt']);
        }

        if($check_password === $row['user_password'])
        {
            // If they do, then we flip this to true
            $login_ok = true;
        }
    }

    // If the user logged in successfully, then we send them to the private members-only page 
    // Otherwise, we display a login failed message and show the login form again 
    if ($login_ok) {

        // Here I am preparing to store the $row array into the $_SESSION by
        // removing the salt and password values from it.  Although $_SESSION is
        // stored on the server-side, there is no reason to store sensitive values
        // in it unless you have to.  Thus, it is best practice to remove these
        // sensitive values first.
        unset($row['user_password']);
        unset($row['user_salt']);       

        // This stores the user's data into the session at the index 'user'.
        // We will check this index on the private members-only page to determine whether
        // or not the user is logged in.  We can also use it to retrieve
        // the user's details.
        $_SESSION['user_email'] = $row;

        $response["success"] = 1;
        $response["message"] = "Login successful!";
        die(json_encode($response));
    } else {
        // Show them their username again so all they have to do is enter a new
        // password.  The use of htmlentities prevents XSS attacks.  You should
        // always use htmlentities on user submitted values before displaying them
        // to any users (including the user that submitted them).  For more information:
        // http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSS_attack
        $submitted_username = htmlentities($_POST['user_email'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');

        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Invalid Credentials!";
        die(json_encode($response));
    }
} else {
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Login</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Login</h1>
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
<p>
<label>Email:</label><br>
<input name="user_email" type="text" value="" maxlength="254"/>
</p>
<p>
<label>Password:</label><br>
<input name="user_password" type="password" value="" maxlength="16"/>
</p>
<p>
<input type="submit" value="Login" name="submit"/>
</p>
</form>
<a href="register.php">Register</a>
</body>
</html>
<?php } ?>
```

LoginActivity.java

```
class AttemptLogin extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         */
        boolean failure = false;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(LoginActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage(getString(R.string.em_AttemptingLogin));
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // Check for success tag
            int success;
            /*String user_name = "";*/
            String user_email = etEmail.getText().toString();
            String user_password = etPassword.getText().toString();
           /* String user_mobile = "";
            String user_country = "";*/
            try {
                // Building Parameters
                List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user_email", user_email));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user_password", user_password));

                Log.d("request!", "starting");
                // getting product detail s by making HTTP request
                JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                        LOGIN_URL, "POST", params);

                // check your log for json response
                Log.d("Login attempt", json.toString());

                // json success tag
                success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                if (success == 1) {
                    Log.d("Login Successful!", json.toString());

                    //SAVE
                    SharedPreferences ui = getSharedPreferences("UserInfo", MODE_PRIVATE);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor edUi = ui.edit();
                    /*edUi.putString("user_name", user_name);*/
                    edUi.putString("user_email", user_email);
                    /*edUi.putString("user_mobile", user_mobile);
                    edUi.putString("user_country", user_country);*/
                    edUi.commit();

                    startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
                    finish();

                    // Returns Toast "Login success!"
                    //return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
                } else {
                    Log.d("Login Failure!", json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE));
                    return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);

                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;

        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * *
         */
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog once product deleted
            pDialog.dismiss();
            if (file_url != null) {
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, file_url, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }

    }
```

I've tried the same way that email but don't work, you can see it's commented /* */ on .java

Thanks

Comment: so, your problem is saving to sharedPreferences and retrieving the data again, right?

Comment: No @cYrixmorten, I've commented your Answer, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to fetch user information with this easy way after a long time of tweaking:

Login.php

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_email = :email";
```

and

```
$response["success"] = 1;
$response["message"] = "Sessão iniciada com sucesso!";
$response["user_name"] = $row['user_name'];
$response["user_mobile"] = $row['user_mobile'];
$response["user_country"] = $row['user_country'];

// echoing JSON response
echo json_encode($response);

//die(json_encode($response));
```

on LoginActivity.java doInBackground

```
String user_name = "";
String user_email = etEmail.getText().toString();
String user_password = etPassword.getText().toString();
String user_mobile = "";
String user_country = "";
```

if success

```
user_name = json.getString("user_name");
user_mobile = json.getString("user_mobile");
user_country = json.getString("user_country");

//SAVE
SharedPreferences ui = getSharedPreferences("UserInfo", MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor edUi = ui.edit();
edUi.putString("user_name", user_name);
edUi.putString("user_email", user_email);
edUi.putString("user_mobile", user_mobile);
edUi.putString("user_country", user_country);
edUi.commit();
```

This was the "easy" way I've found, I know it's not the best but it works just fine! :)

Answer (score 0):

**Server side**

My PHP is rather rusty but I am pretty sure that if you simply echo your json parsed result, then that information is capturen in the JSONObject on your android:

```
echo json_encode($response);
```

**Cracking up the JSONObject**

On your android you should then hopefully have every piece of information from the $result object available.

To pull out that information do something like (unrelated example just to show the mechanics):

```
            JSONObject jsonObject; // ... retreived earlier in the code
            try {

                if (jsonObject.getString("status").equals("OK")) {
                    jsonObject = jsonObject.getJSONArray("results")
                            .getJSONObject(0);
                    jsonObject = jsonObject.getJSONObject("geometry");
                    jsonObject = jsonObject.getJSONObject("location");
                    String lat = jsonObject.getString("lat");
                    String lng = jsonObject.getString("lng");


                    position = new LatLng(Double.valueOf(lat),
                            Double.valueOf(lng));
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
            }
```

**Suggestion regarding shared preferences**

Example saving string in shared preferences and retrieve it again anywhere in your app.

```
public class PreferencesData {

    public static void saveString(Context context, String key, String value) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        sharedPrefs.edit().putString(key, value).commit();
    }

    public static String getString(Context context, String key, String defaultValue) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        return sharedPrefs.getString(key, defaultValue);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
// save a note to the 'mynote' key
PreferencesData.saveString(context, "mynote", "This is a test note");

// retrieve the 'This is a test note' String
String note = PreferencesData.getString(context, "mynote", "");
```

**Optional note:**

I prefer to have as few hard coded strings as possible, so I have a /res/values/strings_prefkeys.xml file that I use to store preference keys. For the note example this file would contain:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="key_note">key_note</string>
</resources>
```

And the above save and retrieval would then become:

```
// save a note to the 'mynote' key
PreferencesData.saveString(context, context.getString(R.string.key_note), "This is a test note");

// retrieve the 'This is a test note' String
String note = PreferencesData.getString(context, context.getString(R.string.key_note), "");
```

This is simply a matter of organisation and minimizing the risk of accidental duplicate keys that would yield some hard to track down bugs.

Comment: Hi, thanks BUT this don't apply to my question. I need to know how to get user information on log in, after that I know how to add it to shared preferences.

Comment: That was not clear to me. Do you not get the data you need in the JSONObject? If so, then you simply need to crack that open and fill it into the sharedPrefs.

Comment: Let me explain: I followed a tutorial. I want to save all users information, except password on my sharedpreferences, but I don't know what I need to change on my .php and my .java to make it works. On my code you can see that I've tried but don't work.